# Calling member procedure NULL SELF argument Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a type `myType` declared with a member procedure `insert_obj`.

When i try this code, i get the following error:

```
declare
   v_obj myType;
begin
   v_obj.insert_obj(1,2,3);
end;

ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
```

I am assuming this is because i have no object on which to call the method...

but i cannot do

```
select value(a) into v_obj from myTable
```

because the table is empty (and i want to insert into it).

How then do i get an object to call my method on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a constructor:

```
v_obj myType := new myType();
```

Comment: No, but you can supply the parameters.