# PL/SQL ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle keeps giving me this error: ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed.

ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

The code follows:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PEDIDO_TP AS OBJECT(
        ID_PEDIDO NUMBER,
        DATA_PAGAMENTO DATE,
        CANCELADO NUMBER(1),
        PENDURADO NUMBER(1),
        member procedure cancelapedido(n in number)
        );
```

`create or replace type body PEDIDO_TP as
  member procedure
  cancelapedido(n in number) is
  begin
         DELETE FROM PEDIDO p
         WHERE p.ID_PEDIDO = n;
  end;
end;

CREATE TABLE PEDIDO OF PEDIDO_TP(
    ID_PEDIDO PRIMARY KEY
);


insert into PEDIDO values (PEDIDO_TP(1,'12/12/12',0,0));

declare 
x PEDIDO_TP;
begin
x.cancelapedido('1');
end;<code>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling member procedure NULL SELF argument Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319022/calling-member-procedure-null-self-argument-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object is null until you create it with a constructor call.  From the Oracle Docs,

> User-defined types, just like collections, are atomically null, until
>   you initialize the object by calling the constructor for its object
>   type

So, you need to do this:

```
declare
x PEDIDO_TP;   --reference to the object

begin
  x := PEDIDO_TP(,,, all your parameters,,,);  --assign created object to the reference.
end;
```

Link to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjplsql.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
**--ORA-30625 (A member method of a type is being invoked with a NULL SELF argument.)**

The issue is simulated with the below cases 

Three Cases:-

**1- Invoking a method without initializing the object 
2- Data is not there in the Payload
3- Data is null in the payload**

--Try to execute the below Scripts 

--CREATE TYPE & TYPE BODY

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYPE AS OBJECT(
        ID  NUMBER,
        DIGIT NUMBER(1),
        member FUNCTION FACT_CAL(n in number) RETURN NUMBER );

create or replace type body TEST_TYPE as
  member FUNCTION FACT_CAL(n in number) RETURN NUMBER is
  begin
    RETURN SELF.ID * SELF.DIGIT * n;
  end;
END;

**--1- Invoking a method without initializing the object** 

--Issue arises here
DECLARE
   r1 TEST_TYPE;
BEGIN
-- R1 := TEST_TYPE(1,2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(R1.FACT_CAL(2));
END;

-----NOW EXECUTE BELOW(issue is resolved here)------

**Solution:-**

DECLARE
   r1 TEST_TYPE;
BEGIN
  R1 := TEST_TYPE(1,2);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(R1.FACT_CAL(2));
END;

**--2- Data is not there in the Payload**

-----EXECUTE BELOW(Issue arises here)------

DECLARE
   r1 TEST_TYPE;
   r2 sys.anydata;
   r3 number;
BEGIN
-- R1 := TEST_TYPE(null,null);
r3:=r2.getObject(r1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_TYPES.SUCCESS);
END;

---Now Execute below(--issue is resolved here)----

**Solution :-** 

DECLARE
   r1 TEST_TYPE;
   r2 sys.anydata;
   r3 number;
BEGIN
-- R1 := TEST_TYPE(null,null);
r2:= sys.anydata.ConvertObject(r1);
r3:=r2.getObject(r1);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(DBMS_TYPES.SUCCESS);
END;

**-- 3- Data is null in the payload**

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_TYPE1 AS OBJECT(
        ID  NUMBER,
        DIGIT NUMBER(1) );

create table anydata 
(id number,
data sys.anydata);

  insert into anydata values (1, null);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_OBJ_TYPE(IN_ANYDATA SYS.ANYDATA)
   RETURN TEST_TYPE1 IS

   V_ANYDATA SYS.ANYDATA := IN_ANYDATA;
   V_BE_DATA TEST_TYPE1 ;
   V_RETURN  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
 V_RETURN := SYS.ANYDATA.GETOBJECT(SELF => V_ANYDATA, OBJ => V_BE_DATA);
 RETURN V_BE_DATA;
END GET_OBJ_TYPE;

--EXECUTE THE QUERY(Issue arises here)

select GET_OBJ_TYPE(data) from anydata;

--NOTE :- PROBLEM IS WHEN THE ANYDATA VALUE IS NULL THIS DATA CANT CONVERT THE PAYLOAD TO SPECIFIC OBJECT TYPE .

-**-SOLUTION** :-

(CONVERT THE 'NULL' ENTRY TO SYS.ANYDATA TYPE) --issue is resolved here


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_OBJ_TYPE(IN_ANYDATA SYS.ANYDATA)
   RETURN TEST_TYPE1 IS

   V_ANYDATA SYS.ANYDATA := IN_ANYDATA;
   V_BE_DATA TEST_TYPE1 ;
   V_RETURN  PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   V_ANYDATA:= sys.anydata.ConvertObject(V_BE_DATA);--- ADD THIS LINE WHICH CONVERTS 'NULL' TO THE SYS.ANYDATA TYPE
   V_RETURN := SYS.ANYDATA.GETOBJECT(SELF => V_ANYDATA, OBJ => V_BE_DATA);

   RETURN V_BE_DATA;
END GET_OBJ_TYPE;

 --NOW EXECUTE THE QUERY`enter code here`
select GET_OBJ_TYPE(data) from anydata;


HOPE THIS IS HELPFUL ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the constructor for this object, and you can do this when you declare the variable. For example:

declare
x PEDIDO_TP := PEDIDO_TP.CONSTRUCT;   --reference to the object and call to constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to oracle ACL (Most probably), at least we could fix this issue by resolving the ACL issue.

Make sure that the port is available for that specific domain

```
select acl , host , lower_port , upper_port from DBA_NETWORK_ACLS;
```

And make sure that the user has sufficient privilege

```
select acl , principal , privilege , is_grant from DBA_NETWORK_ACL_PRIVILEGES;
```

ACL tutorial is [HERE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/fine-grained-access-to-network-services-11gr1)